# What is a subdomain (in relation to IP)?

Tags: ip

My understanding is that when you buy a domain, you buy the right to associate that domain name with ANY IP address you want.

So, if I buy "example.com", I can say that when someone looks up "example.com", they will be directed to `172.16.254.1`. I can also change this IP at a later date.

From what I understand, I also own "whatever.example.com" at that point, but can I point that to some IP address? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can make whatever tree of DNS structures you like under any domain you control -- that's in fact pretty much the purpose of the DNS: being able to delegate portions of the namespace.

This includes having several hosts with different names -- the most common being things like `www.example.com` and `mail.example.com` -- with the same or different addresses as appropriate to the situation.

You are nearly correct about "any address you like": as regards mechanism, you can put any arbitrary in the DNS address records.  However, as regards policy, you are expected not to put private DNS space addresses (such as 192.168.x.y or 172.31.x.y) in public DNS.

[RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) "Address Allocation for Private Internets" says:

> Indirect references to such addresses should be contained within the
> enterprise. Prominent examples of such references are DNS Resource
> Records and other information referring to internal private addresses.
> In particular, Internet service providers should take measures to
> prevent such leakage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I don't really understand. Would it be correct to say that I can route `lol.example.com` to `172.16.111.1` and `sup.example.com` to `999.99.999.9` by making changes to a DNS entry?

Comment: Yes: if you put those records in the DNS it will allow you to have two address for two different hostnames.  But also no: `172.16.111.1` is a private address and *shouldn't* go in the public DNS; and obviously `999.99.999.9` is not a valid IP address and so *can't* be used, as the underlying mechanism is binary not textual and has no way to represent such a thing.

Comment: I just made up those IPs - I don't know what a valid IP is. I think that answers my questions though - thank you!